# Which episode is spoofed in this section of opening sequence?

Tags: azumanga-daioh

Apparently, the opening sequence in Azumanga Daioh spoofs different situations throughout the series. I can't recognize which episode this is from. (Click for full size image.)

[image: Kasuga (Osaka) looks surprised or embarassed, while Kagura and Tomo look frustrated]

Do you know which episode this animation spoofs?

Comment: Reading the description of the tag [Tag:identification-request], I guess it's wrong here, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @looper Actually, the description is a bit out of date: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/545/274

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from Episode 13, **"Tactics without Guard / S / Midterms / Formation / Ability"**, specifically the **Midterms / Formation** portion.

Even more specifically, it's the **'Idiots' / 'Numbnuts' / 'Bonkuras'** formation discussed when comparing midterm grades to the others (where their combined scores add up to 103, but Chiyo's and Yomi's are of course much higher).